# fileno error due to python sh upgrading from 1.11 to 1.12 and above

Tags: python, sh

I am working with sh in python 2, the script works well when the version of sh is 1.11 but when upgrading the version to 1.12 and above an error occurs while running the program. The error is:

```
AttachedBlocks INFO: crypto_drive_handler.get_key: Trying to get key from metadata partition...
Exception in thread STDIN thread for pid 54714:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1637, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2511, in input_thread
    done = stdin.write()
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2818, in write
    chunk = self.get_chunk()
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2749, in fn
    poller.register_read(stdin)
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 187, in register_read
    self._register(f, select.POLLIN | select.POLLPRI)
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 182, in _register
    self._set_fileobject(f)
  File "/home/kevin/block_dev_hook/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 158, in _set_fileobject
    fd = f.fileno()
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Does someone figure what can be the error? Has something changed from 1.11 version to 1.12 versions and above?

I am using

```
sh.dd("if=" + device_path,
      "bs=64k",
      "skip=" + str(i * ENC_KEY_SIZE),
      "count=" + str(ENC_KEY_SIZE),
      "iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes",
      _out=encrypted_key)
```

after "Trying to get key from metadata partition..." info. I can't share more code due to different reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a minimum working example? just the smallest runnable version of your script that creates this error.  Right now, it's a little hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, the code is inside a function that basically does this. First, get the encrypted key with sh.dd() from luks partition then use that key to decrypt using openssl (https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Encrypt_and_decrypt_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html).